# get url attribute in AJAX and pass to the PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

This is ajax.js where I'm calling every 5 seconds boo.php. I want to get this  parameter color from index.php?color=red to process that in var and send in my file boo.php so i can get all the data where the field color is red.

```
var seconds = 5;
var divid = "timediv";
var url = "boo.php";

function refreshdiv(){
---
// Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request
fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}
var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var newurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;
// The code...

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",newurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// Start the refreshing process

var seconds;
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
```

Here is my index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
refreshdiv();
// --></script>
<div id="timediv"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I need this code here

```
var newurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;
```

to be like boo.php?color=red

Thanks a lot. I hope that this can be done :(

Comment: The question is unclear. And the code is formatted very bad. The bracketing is an inconsistent mix of regular and Egyptian brackets, and there is no indenting.

Comment: well lets make simple... how can i get this parameter color from index.php?color=red in the ajax.js

var color = <?php echo $_GET['color']; ?>

Comment: Didn't you just answer your question right there?

Comment: Yes but how can i add this var color to the url: 

Is it correct this var newurl = url+"?color=<?php echo $_GET['color']; >?"+;

Comment: Why is the color presently in a $_GET variable anyway? And no, if that code is inside ajax.js it won't work because it won't run the PHP. You need to clarify the question a lot, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This getQueryVariable JavaScript function should return the color value, so if your site's url is domain.tld?color=red, timestamp value would be red.

var newurl = url+"?color="+timestamp;

```
    function getQueryVariable()
    {
        try{
            v = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
            {
                p = v[i].split("=");
                if(p[0] == "color")
                {
                    if(p[1].indexOf('%20') != -1)
                    {
                        timestamp = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timestamp = p[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```